# How to write list of elements to a XML without surrounding them into object?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have a following model:

```
@Data
@XStreamAlias("id")
public class Group {
    private String id;
    private List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Which after I parse a list of Groups to XML, it will print the following:

```
<group id="..">
  <memberList>
      <member>
       ...
      </member>
      <member>
       ...
      </member>
      <member>
       ...
      </member>
  </memberList>
</group>
```

However, I would like to to save the list without the surrounding object `memberList`:

```
<group id="..">
  <member>
    ...
  </member>
  <member>
    ...
  </member>
  <member>
    ...
  </member>
</group>
```

How can I achive that? I want to be able to handle lists of many different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Never used X-Stream before, but based on its documentation http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html , you can make use of `@XStreamImplicit` annotation

```
@Data
@XStreamAlias("id")
public class Group {
    private String id;

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="member")
    private List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using org.simpleframework.xml and its `@Root` and `@ElementList` annotations, you can simply put `@ElementList(inline=true)` to get rid of additional wrapping elements in the list. It determines whether the element is inlined to the parent XML element.